# Latency on VoIP network

Tags: networking, voip

our network consists of Aruba and Brocade switches.  We have two models of Yealink phones, t21 and T46.  Problem seems to be the t21's 10/100 switch with a PC connected behind it.   the phones are on their own VLAN.  the latency occurs like clockwork from 7:30AM to 3:00PM, When teachers and students are onsite.   Phone vendor says we have too many LLC broadcasts from the Brocades. (Can't explain why not at after 3 PM)   Brocade and HPE engineers see nothing wrong.  the actual complaint is voice calls breaking up and delays when hearing the other person talk.   Can not pin point it to one phone.  It jumps around.   I think it's the T21 switch port.  We had one and we swapped it with a T46 with a PC behind it and that problem went away.  anyone good at reading a PCAP from two different schools to see if my network traffic is normal.  Or any other ideas beside replacing all the T21's

Comment: VoIP can actually stand a lot of latency, but what kills the calls is jitter (changing latency). You probably get a lot of variable congestion, and you should do some real network analysis to determine the exact problem and implement a proper QoS strategy to mitigate the problem.

Comment: We have QoS on that VLAN and had HPE and Brocade check our switch configs.  ENA manages the router so once I get the packet to that router i lose control.   I know the data devices can handle latency without the user knowing too much.  any network device that isn't behind a phone has avg 1 ms ping reply.   Ping replys on the phones go as high as 3000ms at times.   But after 3:00 PM ping times drop to 1 to 5 ms on the phones.

Comment: Ping has nothing to do with VoIP. Ping measures the ICMP protocol, but VoIP uses UDP. You are suffering from congestion, and you claim QoS on the VLAN, but you need to have CoS properly set for the trunks, and DSCP set for the router interfaces. It must be a comprehensive and consistent set of QoS policies from end to end.

Comment: okay,thank you.  Guess my problem is I can't find the congestion.  what bugs me is this in one school of the 11 we have setup all the same.  It's the only one suffering.  Maybe over my head.  ENA who installed the phone system made us put the phones on their on VLAN.  so I thought the congestion would have to be at the uplink port to their router.  since it was happening on calls going out and the phone system is hosted not local.  ENA sees no flooding going to their router. so they say it local LLC flooding on our network?    anyway, appreciate the insight.  I'll keep digging into it.

Comment: Did you say 10/100 switch? There are still such things out there in production?! It might be just congestion from having this ancient beast in the network.

Comment: answer to the Mystery.  Make sure the VoIP phone vender managing the phones turns on "PC port VLAN enable"     Once they made that change, pings went to 0ms, all phones registered, all PC's behind the phones connected.    and voice calls are normal and clear.   Only had to endure a month of them telling us our network had a problem. :)